# Multiple actions on one Button

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WinForms (C#) application, I have created a language menu strip and a sound button but I don't know how to make them switchable.

I mean I want the sound button to stop sound when i hit it & play sound when i hit it again and change its icon as well ?
Similarly, the language menu, how to make it change language with "Localizable" and its text to the other language at first hit, then turn back at second hit ?

Here is my code:

```
using System.Globalization;

using System.Threading;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {}

            private void Menu_LanguageSwitch_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            //Switch to EN - what's here?
            {
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

                System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager res = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form2));
                res.ApplyResources(lbl_Status, "lbl_Status");

                Menu_LanguageSwitch.Text = "Francais";
            }

            //Switch to French
            {
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

                System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager res = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form2));

                res.ApplyResources(Menu_LanguageSwitch, "Menu_LanguageSwitch");
                res.ApplyResources(label2, "label2");
                res.ApplyResources(label3, "label3");
                res.ApplyResources(label4, "label4");
                res.ApplyResources(label5, "label5");
                res.ApplyResources(label6, "label6");
                res.ApplyResources(label7, "label7");
                res.ApplyResources(label8, "label8");
                res.ApplyResources(lbl_Status, "lbl_Status");
                Menu_LanguageSwitch.Text = "Francais";
            }
        }
}
```

Thank you, please make it clear to a beginner. I'ma "rookie".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to keep track of the current state of the program, so you can check against it when the button is pushed. For simple flags (like "Mute") this can just be a bool:

```
private bool isMuted = false;

private void onSoundClick(...)
{
    if (isMuted)
    {
         //Do unmute kind of things
         isMuted = false;
    }
    else
    {
         //Do mute kind of things
         isMuted = true;
    }
}
```

The localization logic would be similar, but if you want it to be more than 2 languages, you'll need to cycle through a list/queue.

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is the use a form scope variable
Externalize  to the form
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr"); 
when you click the button check the active CutureInfo and then switch to the correct